# ChromeDriver doesn't find Element to be clicked

Tags: java, webdriver, instagram

Chrome - WebDriver doesn't find the `log in` button of the Instagram's login page. I have tried 3ways (see below for my code) and in all ways the button does not get clicked on. Any help is highly appreciated!

**Code:**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\scraper - by 
    Url\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("testtest");

    //driver.findElements(By.tagName("button")).get(1).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement button = 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[.='Log in']")));
    button.click();

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log in']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a minor mistake in the xpath, you have used `i` of `Log in` in small letter, however on the page, the word is in camel case, so you need to use `Log In`

**Or**

You can use the below xpath for the `Login` button:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Log In']")));
```